# nest-schedule npm not working

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I am using nest.js framework for developing a node based application. I am trying to write a scheduler using nest-schedule as mentioned at https://www.npmjs.com/package/nest-schedule.

Somehow the code is not working when used with @Cron or @Schedule. Rest other decorators work's fine. Using the same code base as mentioned in above link. Can anyone help me with setting this up and with exact cron pattern used in nodejs

Answer (score 8):

For current version of Nest may you could use nestjs/schedule. See how I achieve this with nestjs/schedule.

1st: install nestjs cli

```
npm i -g @nestjs/cli
```

2nd: Create a new project

```
nest new schedule-sample
```

3rd: Install the nestjs schedule

```
npm install --save @nestjs/schedule
```

4th: Generate a new service to put your service.

```
nest generate service cron
```

Once you have installed the package add it to the app.module as follow below:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ScheduleModule } from '@nestjs/schedule';
import { CronService } from './cron.service';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ScheduleModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [CronService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

5th: you can run it as show bellow (the complete instructions are here https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/task-scheduling):

```
@Cron('*/5 * * * * *')
runEvery10Seconds() {
 console.log('Run it every 5 seconds');
}
```

Here is the complete sample (cron.service.ts).

```
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Cron, Interval } from '@nestjs/schedule';

@Injectable()
export class CronService {

    private readonly logger = new Logger(CronService.name);

    @Cron('*/5 * * * * *')
    runEvery10Seconds() {
        this.logger.debug('Run it every 5 seconds');
    }


    @Cron('10 * * * * *')
    handleCron() {
        this.logger.debug('Called when the current second is 10');
    }

    @Interval(10000)
    handleInterval() {
        this.logger.debug('Called every 10 seconds');
    }
}
```

Final thoughts:
The most sophisticated way to schedule jobs is use dynamic cron jobs. For that you can obtain a reference to a CronJob instance by name from anywhere in your code using the SchedulerRegistry API. First, inject SchedulerRegistry using standard constructor injection:

```
constructor(private schedulerRegistry: SchedulerRegistry) {}
```

HINT
Import the SchedulerRegistry from the @nestjs/schedule package.
Then use it in a class as follows. Assume a cron job was created with the following declaration:

```
@Cron('* * 8 * * *', {
  name: 'notifications',
})
triggerNotifications() {}
```

Access this job using the following:

```
const job = this.schedulerRegistry.getCronJob('notifications');

job.stop();
console.log(job.lastDate());
```

I have tested it at the follow versions (package.json)

```
"@nestjs/common": "^7.6.15",
"@nestjs/core": "^7.6.15",
"@nestjs/schedule": "^0.4.3",
```

Comment: I had to include the `CronService` in my list of `providers`. i.e.
`
@Module({
  imports: [ScheduleModule.forRoot()],
  providers: [CronService],
})
`

Comment: thks for your feed back @n00b

Answer (score 7):

Had the same issue, cron jobs did not start, solved it this way:

```
async function bootstrap() {

  const app = await NestFactory.createApplicationContext(AppModule);
  
  // add this, if network if network listener is needed :
  await app.listen(<port>)

  // or this if network is not needed :
  await app.init()

}

bootstrap();
```

Comment: This works actually.. sepecially if your running the @nestjs/scheduler inside a microservice..  and it looks like bull queue also has the same issue..

adding the "await app.init()" suddenly made our  queue-microservices work

we had another version of the queue-microservice which outright worked, which was due to the microservice was in hybrid mode (microservice + http layer)

Comment: yes, it worked for me as well. It must be a microservice-related issue.

Answer (score 2):

Have you added your job's service to a module?

Maybe your job is not imported into any module.

https://github.com/nestjs/nest/tree/master/sample/27-scheduling/src/tasks

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Answer (score 1):

`@Cron()` and `@Schedule()` decorators did not really work until [v0.3.1](https://github.com/miaowing/nest-schedule/releases/tag/0.3.1) ([github issue](https://github.com/miaowing/nest-schedule/issues/2)).

Could you try the [latest version](https://github.com/miaowing/nest-schedule/releases/tag/0.3.1)?

`package.json`

```
{
    ...
    "dependencies": {
        "nest-schedule": "^0.3.1"
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

`scheduler.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Cron, NestSchedule } from 'nest-schedule';

@Injectable()
export class SchedulerService extends NestSchedule {

    // ...

    @Cron('* * * * * *') // Run every second
    scheduledJob() {
        console.info('[Scheduler]: scheduled jobs has been started');

        // ...
    }

    // ...

}
```

Works for me.

Comment: `import { Cron, Interval, Timeout, NestSchedule, defaults } from 'nest-schedule';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

defaults.retryInterval = 1000;
defaults.enable = true;
defaults.maxRetry = -1;

@Injectable()
export class Scheduler extends NestSchedule {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    // Executar a cada segundo
    @Cron('* * * * *')
    syncData() {
    this.logger.debug('Executando syncData...');
        console.log('scheduler')
    }
}`

Comment: version ~0.4.5 in package.json

Answer (score 1):

Note that the decorator is used in the declarative definition.

NOT WORKING:

```
@Cron(CronExpression.EVERY_10_SECONDS)
async task() {
    console.log('[Scheduler]: every 10 seconds');
}
```

WORKING:

```
@Cron(CronExpression.EVERY_10_SECONDS)
task() {
    console.log('[Scheduler]: every 10 seconds');
}
```

Comment: it _does_ work for me with the `async` notation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue... Doing some research I found I need to use the latest version of @nestjs/common and @nestjs/core and if used also  @nestjs/platform-express